# CSRF-protection for routes of proxied requests in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, http-proxy

I'm using `http-proxy-middleware` (and open to suggestions, but would like to stick to the modules which are proxying requests instead of creating new ones like `request` or `http`) to proxy requests to remote host.

Two problems I'm not seeing solutions to currenty:

1) I have a CSRF-protected form (via `csurf`). I would like it that the middleware checks the CSRF-token first, and in case it is valid only then proxies the request to another host, obtains the response and sends it to user. How to achieve such a setup?

2) `http-proxy-middleware` (and some other proxying modules) utilizes `app.use` to set one forwarding rule (append the route to the host), however I would like to have a more fine-grained control over routes - each of my routes must have its own endpoint on the remote host.

The code:

```
const express = require('express')
const csrf = require('csurf')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

var app = express()
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })
app.use(cookieParser())

// not quite what I need, since different 
// routes would utilize different endpoints
app.use('/api', proxy('http://example.com'))

app.get('/forms', (req, res) => {
  res.send(
    res.render('csrf-protected-forms.html', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
  )
})

app.post('/api/one', csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
  response = // proxies to 'http://example.com/something/one' 
             // and obtains response
  res.send(response)
})

app.post('/api/two', csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
  response = // proxies to 'http://example.com/somethingelse/and/here/two' 
             // and obtains response
  res.send(response)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `csrf` protection runs after proxied middleware. In case if you want protect only this two routes `'/api/one','/api/two'`:

```
app.use(['/api/one','/api/two'], csrfProtection, proxy('http://example.com'))
app.use('/api', proxy('http://example.com'))
```

Or if you want protect all `POST` requests to API, you need somthing this:

```
app.use('/api', csrfProtection, proxy('http://example.com'))
```